# How to show 'the most popular name' in each year using SQL

Tags: sql

I am practicing SQL in Google Cloud Platform and have a table with the most popular names in USA. 
I need to write a query that  returns the most popular name in every year.
The Table has 6 columns: id, state, gender, year, name, Number of occurrences of the name

So far I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year
FROM 'table'
```

But I don't now what next...

Comment: Well, you have year, but not name. Maybe add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the called the `mode` in statistics.  One way to get this uses aggregation and window fucntions:

```
select year, name
from (select year, name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
     from t
     group by year, name
    ) yn
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above version returns one arbitrary name if there are ties for the most frequent.  If you do want ties, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.